# Safe API with tagged values

Tags: ffi, agda

Many libraries have an interface where one must first call a function to initialize the library, which returns some value (often a pointer, sometimes called a "context" or "handle") to pass to other functions, for example (in C):

```
Library *initialize(long flags);
A mkA(Library *library, long n);
B mkB(Library *library, A a);
```

Calling `mkB` if `a` was not created with the same context `library` is an error.

I want to bind the API in Agda (thru Haskell), and enforce the same-context requirement in the type system, but am not sure how to do so safely. (Note the API is pure in that `mkA` for example returns an equivalent value each time it is called with the same arguments.) My idea of the API is as follows:

```
module Data.Tagged where
open import Level
data Tagged {ℓ ℓ′} {A : Set ℓ} (a : A) (B : Set ℓ′) : Set (ℓ ⊔ ℓ′) where
    tag : B → Tagged a B
```

```
module Raw where
    postulate
        Library A B HsWord : Set
        initialize : IO Library
        mkA : Library → HsWord → A
        mkB : Library → A → B
    {-# COMPILE GHC Library = type Library #-}
    {-# COMPILE GHC A = type A #-}
    {-# COMPILE GHC B = type B #-}
    {-# COMPILE GHC HsWord = type Word #-}

open import Data.Tagged
open Raw public using (Library)
module _ {lib : Library} where
    A B : Set
    A = Tagged lib A
    B = Tagged lib B
    mkA : Raw.HsWord → A
    mkA n = tag (Raw.mkA lib n)
    mkB : A → B
    mkB a = tag (Raw.mkB lib a)
```

Thus type safety would be ensured — `mkB` accepts only `A` values made with the same `Library` — except one can write the following term:

```
castTagged : ∀ {a a′ B} → Tagged a B → Tagged a′ B
castTagged (tag b) = tag b
```

I would make the definitions

```
A = Tagged lib A
B = Tagged lib B
```

abstract, except so they would become irreducible even in other type signatures in the same module. I'd like to be able to define these to be reducible in the same module but irreducible elsewhere but am not sure it's possible. I would like to keep `Data.Tagged` in a separate module so i can prove other theorems about it there, rather than redefine it for each library i want to bind.

Anyhow, how can one define such a tag-safe API in Agda?